# Folders Created in Open with Explorer doesn't show on site

Tags: open-with-explorer

I have created folders and sub-folders in "Open with explorer" but they don't show online.

It does however show when you use the "Open with explorer" option. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Which location you created those folders?

Comment: I created the folders using "open with explorer" function. I created several folders and sub-folders. They don't appear on the SharePoint site though.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a folder outside of a document library then you wont see it in SharePoint but you will see it in explorer view its a folder though and not a doc library so no way to display that in SharePoint itself - you must make sure all users only add folders inside those already created (which are actually doc libraries but look like folders - you can see why the confusion happens!!) or add the doc library to SharePoint first.

I'm just looking around now to find a way to stop people being able to add folders to a site root that will never show up in SP! Anyone know??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your view and confirm that "Show items inside folders" is checked, rather than "Show all items without folders".

With that said, using folders and subfolders in a SharePoint library is generally frowned upon. In my opinion they should really only be used under four circumstances: managing security, managing large views, avoiding duplicate filenames, and taking advantage of location-based metadata. If you're not using them for one of these reasons, you're probably better off using columns, views, or separate document libraries to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue in SharePoint 2016, a folder was not showing in browser but only in explorer view.
The problem was in the name of the folder "00_H_and_S**_FILE**" the suffix **_FILE** is not accepted by SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have the number of items shown limited - you might want to show it in batches of 30, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons is:
The specified item or folder name is too long.
The URL path for ALL items and folders must be 260 characters or less 
(AND no more then 128 characters for ANY single item or folder name in the URL).